# What is the browser default color for links?

Tags: css, inheritance, cascading

I'm reading about Controlling inheritance using universal values in this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance).

I don't get why third link is black if browser default color for links is blue (is that correct?).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        body {
            color: green;
        }

        .inherited a {
            color: inherit;
        }

        .reset a {
            color: initial;
        }

        .unset a {
            color: unset;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li>Default <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
        <li class="inherited">Inherit the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
        <li class="reset">Reset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
        <li class="unset">Unset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The default color for links is blue  but here you are setting the attribute for 'li' the initial color for 'li' is black so that is the reason you're link is turning into a black one